# SQL Returning Values using count that has a duplicate record

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables and am trying to return the names of all students who are enrolled in two classes and the classes meet at the same time.

```
select student.sname, count(erolled.snum) as TotalClassesEnrolledIn, count(distinct class.meets) as MostClassesAtOneTime from student
    inner join erolled on erolled.snum=student.snum
    inner join class on class.cname=erolled.cname
group by student.sname
having count(erolled.snum) > 1 and count(Distinct class.meets) > 1
```

It returns the student name and the number of classes they are taking however it list only the students that have no conflicting class times.

Is there a way to change the Count field to only display only display people who have classes at the exact same time?

Answer (score 0):

To show all students that have at least 1 pair of classes at the exact time, change `having count(distinct class.meets) > 1`, which requires that students have more than 1 distinct class meeting time, to `count(distinct class.meets) < count(class.meets)`, which requires that at least one of the `class.meets` times are identical.